# подключение телеграм-бота на webhook к веб-серверу Apache

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток всем!

Передали нам бота, написанный на python с веб-сервером. У меня на сервере уже развёрнут Apache. Бота с url связал (setWebhook), но бот молчит. Как я могу подключить бота к своему веб-серверу? И вообще можно ли это сделать с Apache?

Я с ботами на Вы, прошу прощения, если пишу непонятный бред!)

Кусок кода со стартом:

```
def main(argv):
if len(argv) > 0:
    init_manager(app)
    return
else:
    init_database(app)
if config['bot']['polling']:
    logger.info('starting polling...')
    thread = Thread(target=bot_polling)
    thread.start()
else:
    logging.info('setting webhook...')
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(config['bot']['webhook'])
me = bot.get_me()
logger.info('Me: %s @%s', me.first_name, me.username)
# init_commands()
socketio.run(app, host=config['server']['host'], port=config['server']['port'], use_reloader=False,
             debug=config['server']['debug'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я решил свою проблему.
Так как `socketio` подключается к локальному серверу, я использовал прокси в Apache:
В файле \Apache\conf\httpd.conf раскомментировать строки:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

В файле \Apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf добавить следующий виртуальный хост:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName domen.name.ru
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests On
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3003/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile *.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile *.key
</VirtualHost>
```

В `socketio` указать `localhost` и порт `3003`.